# New line appearing while it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I am really new to CSS and I am trying to display the data of a person as an example. Format goes: `Details
Name: John`

etc but `Name:` must be in gold. I use:

```css
h1 {
  color: gold;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 100%;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Details</h2>
<h1>Name:</h1> 
<h2>John</h2>
```

Which quite works except the fact that `John` goes under `Name:` despite no using a new line or something...

Comment: The html is doing that, not the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.example{
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: 100%;
}

.title {
  color: gold;

}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h1>Details</h1>
  <span class="title">Name:</span>  John
</div>
```

`h1` and `h2` adds a new line by default. H stands for header, so it's considered bad practice to use headers for styling non header content.
You can add another css rule `display: inline` and it will solve your problem, but I would also recommend using the `span` tag instead of the `h1` and `h2` tags

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. works good but why is "Details" a biit larger than other letters?

Comment: As I mentioned, `h1` tag is for headers, so the default size of the text is larger. You can change it to `span` and the text won't be larger.

Answer (score 2):

`h1` and `h2`are block elements and will always go into new lines.

Either you can use a `span`tag inside a `h1` tag, like

```
<h1><span class="my_style1">Name:</span> John</h1>
```

with CSS

```
.my_style1 {
  color: gold; 
}
```

...or you make h1 and h2 inline:

```
h1, h2 { display: inline; }
```

..., WHICH I DON'T RECOMMEND, since it will bring a lot of other troubles...

Comment: But please don't get into the habit of naming your CSS classes after the styles they represent. Don't call this class `gold`, call it `fancy` or `jumpy` or something else that describes the use case for the class rather than its style.

Comment: @Welbog yes, true - I wanted to make it more obvious - I'm gonna change it in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

That is how the HTML tags you're using work by default. The newlines in your HTML document mean nothing to the browser.

There are a few ways to accomplish what you're doing. I added a class to both the h1 and h2 tags and used display:inline to do it:

New HTML:

```
<h2>Details</h2>
<h1 class="inline">Name:</h1> <h2 class="inline">John</h2>
```

New CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: gold;
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 100%;
}
h2 {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 100%;
}

.inline {
  display:inline;
}
```

Other methods, such as simply using a span tag work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to html/css!

So h1 and h2 elements will automatically behave a certain way to due to basic styles that come 'default' with them. In this case, h1's and h2's like to be on their own lines. Even though you've placed them on the same line in your HTML, after the browser loads it, they will do their own thing.

Here's an example of styles you could apply to remedy that:

```
h1,h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is telling the h1 and h2 elements to sit on the same line with each other. That said, They will also attempt to sit on the same line as the h2 element you're attempting to keep on its own line. This might be a good time to differentiate between your elements by applying classes.

```
<h2>Details</h2>
<h1>Name:</h1>
<h2 class="subheading">John</h2>
```

Then, your final styles might look like this:

```
h1, .subheading {
display: inline-block;
}
```